# DietJS: Respond with specific response code

Tags: node.js, diet-js

Going through all of the tutorials of `DietJS` here: [Diet.js | Tutorials](http://dietjs.com/tutorials), I am not able to find a way to respond with a particular response code.

In the signals section, it is mentioned that we can use:

```
$.failure();
```

And we can put in more information about the failure through:

```
$.error("username", "missing");
```

But it responds with code 200 by default. There are no direct pointers towards setting up the desired response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time I figured out that you can actually do:

```
$.status(401, "Bad Request");
```

before you end the request with `$.end()`, `$.failure()` or any other alternatives.